# Mudar formatação de um link

Tags: html, css

pessoal. Gostaria de saber como aplicar um sublinhado em um link assim que uma pessoa posiciona o mouse sobre um texto com um.

Eu removi o sublinhado do link com `text-decoration: none` e gostaria de aplicar o sublinhado apenas quando alguém posicionasse o mouse sobre link.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com o `a:hover` (quando o mouse passar por cima).

Veja um exemplo executando o código abaixo:

```css
/*  CSS */

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  }

a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
  }
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->    


<a href="">Link teste</a>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado =)

Answer (score 0):

Os links já possuem uma formatação padrão, que na verdade não
são tão atraentes, então podemos alterar e deixar da maneira que
quiser.

Os links possuem quatro estados, são eles:

- Link --- Links não visitados
- Visited --- Links Visitados
- Hover --- Links Hover, quando passa o cursor sobre o link
- Active --- Links Ativos, quando clicado

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

```
 a{
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

/*A tag a serve para editar todos os links de uma vez*/

```
  a:link{
  background-color: #6D790F;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  }
```

/*Mudar links não visitados*/

```
  a:visited{
    color: #c0c0c0;
  }
```

/*Mudar links visitados*/

```
  a:hover{
    color: black;
  }
```

/*Quando passa o cursor sobre o link*/

```
  a:active{
    color: blue;
  }
```

/*Links Ativos, quando clicado*/

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).